# Steam - Disable Two Factor Authentication

Tags: steam

Is there a way to disable the Steam two factor authentication?  In other words, when I type my user and pwd, I want to be logged in.  I don't want to wait for Steam to email me some code if it "doesn't recognize me".

I have looked through the steam client settings and I can't find a setting for disabling the email.

Comment: You are right, basically a dup, but will leave the question here in case anyone was like me and didnt know the name for steam's two factor auth system

Answer (score 5):

Its called steamguard - and disabling it will turn off your ability to turn use the steam market. You can turn it off under settings.

[image]

Comment: Does that prevent playing multi player games or have any bearing on the anti cheat system?

Comment: I don't think so - I don't play MP stuff for the most part, but I don't see why it would.

Comment: And you are showing an animation as part of the answer, which is awesome.  How did you do that?  Is it a gif?

Comment: Yup. I use licecap - I have an answer on it on super user http://superuser.com/questions/81826/how-do-i-create-a-gif-screencast-in-windows/657800#657800

Comment: I don't know how easy it is with that software, but in general I would always suggest blurring your email out before posting it in a public place.

Comment: Not easy, and oh crud. Then again, considering I use this *everywhere*, I can't really be bothered to fix it.

Comment: Nice animation, though I do not recommend disabling steam guard, I have been almost hacked and lost all my stuff more than once. Steam guard is there for a reason...